# CWAC Camera - Implement a custom gui

Tags: java, android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the library created by commonsware to make a simple camera application. In the read me there is a section that states this:

> You can subclass CameraFragment and override onCreateView(). Chain to
>   the superclass to get the CameraFragment's own UI, then wrap that in
>   your own container with additional widgets, and return the combined UI
>   from your onCreateView().

I'm still not great with Android Fragments so I was hoping someone could explain this to me a little bit better.

I have two activities (A, B), one fragment (CamFragment), and two layouts (A, B). My first activity (A) loads a layout (A) that has a single button and imageView. The button starts the second activity (B), which loads the fragment (CamFragment) with the second layout (B). The second layout is taken from the demo app:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

So, now in my application, I want a button on the camera fragment/second activity that will takePicture() onClick. Following the instructions given in the readme, I need to subclass CameraFragment first. This is easy and I just do:

```
public class CamFragment extends CameraFragment {
```

Next, I have to override onCreateView. Again, a trivial task just like in the v9 demo.

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    setHost(new DemoCameraHost(getActivity()));
  }
```

The next part is where I really get confused, and I hope someone can help.

> Chain to the superclass to get the CameraFragment's own UI, then wrap
>   that in your own container with additional widgets, and return the
>   combined UI from your onCreateView().

I'm just not entirely sure what that means/entails. It would be awesome if there was a demo, that showed a custom camera UI without the actionBar, as I feel like most developer won't put the controls into the action bar.

### EDIT #1:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View uiFromParent=super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View yourUi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_cam, container, false);
    View theThingThatWillHoldThePreview = yourUi.findViewById(R.id.holder); // or whatever
    ((ViewGroup) theThingThatWillHoldThePreview).addView(uiFromParent); // with some appropriate LayoutParams
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

main_cam.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/abs__bright_foreground_holo_dark"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/abs__bright_foreground_holo_dark"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="Capture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

cam_fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Next, I have to override onCreateView. Again, a trivial task just like in the v9 demo.

Your code is not overriding `onCreateView()`. It overrides `onCreate()`.

> I'm just not entirely sure what that means/entails.

"Chain to the superclass to get the CameraFragment's own UI"

```
View uiFromParent=super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

"then wrap that in your own container with additional widgets"

```
View yourUi=... // inflate something, create straight in Java, whatever
View theThingThatWillHoldThePreview=yourUi.findViewById(...); // or whatever

theThingThatWillHoldThePreview.addView(uiFromParent, ...); // with some appropriate LayoutParams
```

"and return the combined UI from your onCreateView()"

```
return(yourUi);
```

Comment: Sorry, for the first part `onCreateView`, do I plug that into the fragment or the activity?

Comment: @GuyLeStack: "do I plug that into the fragment or the activity?" -- `onCreateView()` goes in your subclass of `CameraFragment`.

Comment: Okay, so for the bottom part of your solution, I'm a bit confused. I'm not super familiar with layouts and inflating them and such (except for just setContentView). Shouldn't uiFromParent and yourUi be the same. Sorry, I really appreciate your answer, but I still "don't get it". In my head... I should grab the UI, and add a button to it somehow. Yeah in your pseudo code there's seemingly 3 View objects that are the root layouts/views.

Comment: @GuyLeStack: "Shouldn't uiFromParent and yourUi be the same" -- no. `uiFromParent` is what *I* am creating for a UI (a `CameraView`). `yourUi` is the UI that *you* are creating (from wherever) and that you are placing *my* UI into.

Comment: @GuyLeStack: Bear in mind, of course, that you don't have to do any of this. Put my fragment alongside the rest of your UI. The subclassing approach would be if you absolutely needed to have the `CameraView` somewhere that a `CameraFragment` cannot go. Or, quoting my documentation, "You can put that UI as a peer to the CameraFragment, such as by having action bar items, as the demo apps do". You can have two fragments (mine and yours), or three fragments (mine and two of yours), or my fragment and a batch of other widgets of yours, etc.

Comment: The reason why I am trying to follow your method, is because I originally had my second activity have the camera fragment as the background, and the buttons were placed on top of it (using a relative layout). It works well on a lot of devices, but on some devices I get unexpected results (freezing, and scrambled output) that I don't get from the sample application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37755/discussion-between-guylestack-and-commonsware)

Comment: Is this what you meant by `yourUi`: `View yourUi=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);`

Comment: @GuyLeStack: That is certainly one way to create `yourUi`, though I would recommend `inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false)`. IOW, you do it the same way you would for any fragment.

Comment: I tried: `View yourUi = inflate(R.layout.myLayout, container, false);` but I get a "The method inflate(int, ViewGroup, boolean) is undefined for the type CamFragment" EDIT: Oh. inflater.inflate(...)

Comment: So the next line is: View theThingThatWillHoldThePreview = yourUi.findViewById(); //What view am I trying to find? I don't understand... isn't the thing that will hold the preview already set in the "second activity"? Am I not supposed to `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_cam);` in my activity?

Comment: @GuyLeStack: "What view am I trying to find?" -- the container that will hold the `CameraView` that is being set up by `CameraFragment`. Presumably, this would be the same `RelativeLayout` that failed for you before and probably will fail for you again, as this work is unlikely to resolve "freezing and scrambled output" from having widgets float atop the `CameraView`. I would recommend that you simply not have widgets be atop the `CameraView`, but instead have your widgets to one side.

Comment: @GuyLeStack: Eventually, I will work out a recipe for having widgets be able to float on top of a `CameraView`, when I resolve [issue #26](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/26).

Comment: Okay, I am going to post my code, just so that you can point out if something is incorrect. It's currently not working, but I think I'm closer than ever. Look at my edit #1 in my question.

Comment: @GuyLeStack: `return(yourUi);`, please, from `onCreateView()`. Otherwise, everything else you just did was a waste, and your app will probably crash to boot from having more than one active `CameraView`.

Comment: Where should I listen for the buttonClick? Inside of the fragment onCreateView? Because when I do that it crashes... but besides that... it now loads up, I just need to trigger takePicture()

Comment: @GuyLeStack: Call `findViewById()` to retrieve your `ImageButton` in `onCreateView()`, then call `setOnClickListener()` on it.

Comment: Tried this... but it's crashing (inside of onCreateView)
`ImageButton button = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    takePicture();

   }
  });
  return(yourUi);`

Comment: @GuyLeStack: Call `findViewById()` *on `yourUi`, where your `ImageButton` is*, to retrieve your `ImageButton` in `onCreateView()`. This is no different than in any other fragment that you have created, or in `getView()` of an `ArrayAdapter`, or in `bindView()` of a `CursorAdapter`, etc. And, if you have never created a fragment before, messing around with extending `CameraFragment` this way is a really lousy place to learn. Fragments have been around for ~2.5 years. Here's a free book that covers them and other stuff besides: http://commonsware.com/Android/Android-3_7-CC.pdf

Comment: Ah.Okay, great. That worked. Trying this on the Droid Razr Maxx HD still ends up with a frozen preview. Though... =(

Comment: @GuyLeStack: Yeah, as I indicated, I did not expect this to improve matters any. I'll spend some time on it in coming weeks. Again, try having your widgets to the side of the `CameraFragment`/`CameraView`, instead of floating on top, and you should have better luck, if not necessarily the UI you were aiming for.

Comment: Bonus find: If I switch the camera to the front facing camera, and then I switch back again to the rear camera, the preview works fine.

Comment: I did a little more debugging now, and found out that the custom UI (the way I was originally doing it) was NOT causing scrambled output or freezing. It was actually my line of code in activity causing it to mess up. I tried out your CameraDemo - Layout recently and added `this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` and this caused even the layout demo to crash on my droid phone.

Comment: I took the line out, and it still hides the status bar (goes full screen). Is that something your library automatically does?

Comment: Ah. Sorry, ran the wrong project. But, my previous comment was correct. Adding `this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` makes it freeze only on the Droid device. The device is API level 16, and Android tells you to use a different method for 16 and higher (decorView.setSystemUiVisibility). Even though `this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); ` still works even on my api level 19 devices. Weird.

Comment: Also, this leads me to believe that maybe doing the work that is going on in the CameraDemo-Layout was unnecessary. And may have made Issue 26 https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/26 unnecessary as well.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare! You answer most of my questions before I can ask them!